# Why does Terminal say 'Kernel: (unsupported)' when I update?

Tags: kernel, updates

I had to update the next kernel because livepatch was coming up with a lot of bug messages and most of the solutions I found said I had to update the kernel. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.
The livepatch bugs are gone but now I have terminal saying '(unsupported)' when I run update/livepatch update.

What does it mean and what do I do?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336122/edit) to show us complete, actual output showing the problem. More detail is better. A summary or paraphrase is too vague.

Comment: How did you update the kernel ?